# How to use data from a txt file and run it in a method that a user picks?

Tags: java

So I have program that determines the number of creatures called Tribbles in a generation. I have two methods that uses two different ways of getting the solution, a recursive method and an iterative method. My methods are created so that for generation n:

- if N<2 then 1 tribble exists.
- if N=2 then 2 tribble exists.
- if N=3 then 4 tribble exists.
- if N>3 then gen(n-1)+gen(n-2)+gen(n-3)+gen(n-4)

Now with that said, I have a data1.txt file that have random numbers for example:

> 8
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 30
>
> 67

My question is how do I ask a question to the user for a file name and also ask them what type of algorithm to use (im only working on option 1 & 2 so far) and get the integers from the file and print out the number of tribbles exist for each generation.
For example for the numbers above it should print:

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 4
>
> 8
>
> 15
>
> 201061985

and so on.

Thanks in advance and please I would definitely like your help!

PS. For my readfile im placing all my data I get from the file in an array and for my options I'm using those data in the array and use one of my solution methods.

```
public class TribbleAnalysis {

//Fields

public static long n;
public static String fileName;

//Methods

public long genRec(){  
    
    return genRec(n);  
    
}

private static long genRec(long n){  
    
    if(n < 2)
        return 1;
    else if( n == 2)
        return 2;
    else if( n == 3)
        return 4;
    else
        return genRec(n-1)+genRec(n-2)+genRec(n-3)+genRec(n-4);
    
} 

public static long genIter(int n){

    long[] myArray = new long[67];
    myArray[0] = 1;
    myArray[1] = 1;
    myArray[2] = 2;
    myArray[3] = 4;
    
    for(int i=4; i <= n; i++){
        myArray[i] = myArray[i-1]+myArray[i-2]+myArray[i-3]+myArray[i-4];
    }
    
    return myArray[n];

}

public static void optionOne(String fileName){
    
    List<Integer> myNumbers = readFile(fileName);
    
    for (int i=0; i<myNumbers.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(genRec(i));
    }
    
}

public static void optionTwo(String fileName){
    
    List<Integer> myNumbers = readFile(fileName);
    
    for (int i=0; i<myNumbers.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(genIter(i));
    }
    
}

public static void optionThree(String fileName){
    
}

public static void optionFour(String fileName){
    
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
public static List<Integer> readFile(String filename){
    
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    File file = new File(filename + ".txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String text = null;

        while (text != null) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(text));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       System.out.println("Problem opening file " + filename + ".txt" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return list;
    
}

public static void writeFile(String filename){
    
    PrintWriter outFile = null;
    
    try{
        outFile = new PrintWriter(filename + ".csv");
        
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Problem opening file" + filename + ".csv" + e.getMessage());
    }
    
    outFile.close();
    
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //System.out.println(genRecurs(30));
    //System.out.println(genIter(30));
    //System.out.println(" ");
    
    char option;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    boolean isValid = false;
    do{
    
    System.out.println("Menu:" + "\n" + "0) Exit" + "\n" + "1) Run recursive solution without timing and display results to the monitor" + "\n" 
    + "2) Run iterative solution without timing and display results to the monitor" + "\n"
    + "3) Run recursive solution with timing and prints results to a file" + "\n" 
    + "4) Run iterative solution with timing and prints results to a file" + "\n" 
    + " " );
    
    System.out.print( "Please choose an option: ") ;
    option = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    if(option == '1')
        System.out.println("Okay");
    
    else if(option == '2')
        System.out.println("Okay");
    
    else if(option == '3')
        System.out.println("Okay");
    
    else if(option == '4')
        System.out.println("Okay");
    
    else if(option == '0')
        isValid = true;
    
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a valid option: ");
        option = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    }
    
    }while (option == '1'|| option == '2' || option == '3' || option == '4' || option == '0' && isValid == false);
    
    System.out.print( "\n" + "Please choose a file: ") ;
    fileName = keyboard.next();
    
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? Have you taken a look through Google and/or the Java API?

Comment: yes I have looked but everything seems confusing so I decided to get help from here and also hopefully get an explanation on how they did it.

Comment: Typically when you post here (some) people like to see some evidence of things you tried, as well as questions that aren't "Here's what I want to do, tell me how to do it!" Do you have a specific question about what you read that's making things difficult for you?

Comment: what i've tried is i've asked for a file and also an option and I printed out my option1(filename); and it didn't work

Comment: Well, why didn't it work? We can't read your mind.

Comment: i'm not sure either that's why i'm here to ask. after I printed it, it didn't print anything at all

Comment: Be more specific! What's "it"? What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Also, would you like to move this to chat? Might be easier to talk there than in the comments section

Comment: it says I dont have enough reputation to chat, also what I wanted to print like I explained in my question was the amount of tribbles existed.

Comment: Well darn. I'll help you here then. From what it looks like you at the very least have a `Scanner` set up and are trying to read from a file. First thing, what *specifically* is not working? User interaction, reading a file, what?

Comment: Well I think to start of, my user interaction is wrong. I don't think it's actually doing what I want it to do which is to pick a file, then pick an option for it to run.

Comment: So you want to pick a file first, then pick an option? That should be an easy fix, right? Also, two things. Are you familiar with Java's `switch` statement? And you know `Scanner` has a `nextInt()` method?

Comment: Im not familiar with switch and yes I do know it has a nextInt()

Comment: Look it up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)! It's a lot better than a big `if-else` tree. Why not use `nextInt()` instead of what you have to pick an option?

Comment: One more thing -- `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so you might want to add some parentheses to the condition in your `do-while` loop

Answer (score 0):

Go step by step..

The approach would be:

1. Ask for the filename in the next step once you have received the options from the user..
2. Call your function Option1(filename)..
3. Form the file path "C:\folder1\" + filename (Ensure that you run this application as an Administrator, by clicking "Run as Administrator"
4. Also give permissions for the folder before running the application.
5. Once you get the list of integers from the file you should be able to do whatever operations you desire to do..

More specifics might help you resolve the problem.

Hope this helps you...